# How to delete part of a path in an interactive shell?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

Is there a shortcut in bash and zsh to delete one component of a path? For example, if I type `ls ~/local/color/`, and the cursor is at the end of line, is there a shortcut to delete the `color/` at the end? Ideally I want solutions in both vi-mode and emacs-mode

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The most commonly used commands in the default bash *emacs mode*, for most commonly used keyboards:

#### Movement

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>p</kbd>, or <kbd>Up</kbd>: previous command
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>n</kbd>, or <kbd>Down</kbd>: next command
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd>, or <kbd>Left</kbd>: previous character
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd>, or <kbd>Right</kbd>: next character
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd>: previous word
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd>: next word
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd>, or <kbd>Home</kbd>: begin of command
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>e</kbd>, or <kbd>End</kbd>: end of command

#### Editing

- <kbd>BkSpc</kbd>: delete previous character
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd>, or <kbd>Del</kbd>: delete current character
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>BkSpc</kbd>: delete word to left
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd>: delete word to right
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>u</kbd>: delete to start of command
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>k</kbd>: delete to end of command
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>y</kbd>: paste last cut

#### Miscellanea

- <kbd>Cltr</kbd>-<kbd>/</kbd>: undo
- <kbd>Cltr</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd>: incremental backward history search

Comment: Complement: set a shortcut for this purpose in zsh `bindkey [key] vi-backward-kill-word`

Comment: Thanks.  I added this to my ~/.zshrc file and it works well for me when I press Alt+Backspace:  bindkey "^[^?" vi-backward-kill-word.  It's not ideal.

Comment: Alt-Bckspc and Alt-d work well with the filepaths I've tried them on. (on bash)

Comment: Unfortunately, this only answers the question for Bash, not Zsh.

Answer (score 14):

There's also `unix-filename-rubout` for `Readline`!

```
# in ~/.inputrc
# press ctrl-b to delete unix filename parts
# see: man bash | less -p 'unix-filename-rubout' and
#      http://www.calmar.ws/vim/vi-bash.html
set editing-mode vi
set keymap vi
"\C-b": unix-filename-rubout
```

Comment: IMHO `unix-filename-rubout` is the correct answer to the question asked as it deletes to slash or whitespace, whereas `Alt-BkSpc` will stop at characters like hyphen, underscore, dot, etc.

Answer (score 7):

By default bash (and I'm guessing zsh) will be in emacs-mode. You could try something like this:

<kbd>Esc + b</kbd> will put the cursor back one word.
<kbd>Ctrl + k</kbd> will delete until the end of the line.

Most modern shells (like bash) will implement advanced command line editing features. Those commands are either close to emacs editing (Ctrl +A for line beginning, Ctrl + E for line end, ...).

If you're familar with vi-like editors, you could try to allow vi-mode.

`set -o vi`

It gives your shell vi-like modes (command mode/insert mode), and you get access to the standard commands (d for delete, r for replace, ...)

In Vi Mode, here's how you would do what you described:

```
Esc (command mode); d; b.
```

Comment: I would not say "Command line editing is even more powerful and complete in vi-mode", *emacs mode* has commands to do everything you can do in *vi mode*.

Comment: I admit I got a bit carried away. I'll rephrase this.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me there is vi-mode in bash, so I can use `db` in this scenario in bash. I also found `vi-backward-kill-word` in zsh is what I want, and it is more convenient than set vi-mode in bash. But I still want to find an *emacs mode* shortcut for this purpose in bash.

Comment: Or "alt-b-C".  This way doesn't leave a trailing character, which `db` does in some cases.