# How to remove last part of a path in bash?

Tags: bash, readline

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to delete part of a path in an interactive shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-to-delete-part-of-a-path-in-an-interactive-shell)

Is there a short-cut in bash that lets you delete the last part of a path?

Example: `/usr/local/bin` should become `/usr/local/` (or `/usr/local`)

I know of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> but it deletes the complete last word and I'd like to retain that functionality, too.

Comment: <Esc> <BackSpace> on prompt commandline of the shell from the end.

Comment: @Siggy... You've mentioned `Ctrl-w`.. this is a key-combination which has nothing to do with `bash`. Key-combinations like this are for a user interface, like the terminal or text-editor or menus.. They are pretty much meaningless in a bash script... The command-line is not itself `bash`; it belongs to the terminal which passes the commands on to bash (or whatever shell you are running)... Your question is, at a glance, ambiguous; that is why you have two different types of answers...

Answer (score 65):

In a path, it's quite easy, `dirname` takes off the last component of the path.  And since it's a program (as opposed to a builtin) it's completely portable between shells.

```
$ dirname /usr/local/bin
/usr/local
```

---

It appears you mean while editing an active line at the prompt.  In that case Nikhil's comment of <kbd>esc</kbd> <kbd>backspace</kbd> (consecutively, not both at the same time) is correct.

Comment: The question is about command line edition, not about string manipulation.

Comment: I see.  @nikhil you should post that comment as an answer so I can delete this. Or at least so Siggy can accept it.

Comment: Do not know, maybe does not answer the question but I Googled for string manipulation, found this and I am happy so upvoting.

Answer (score 11):

Assuming, you are using emacs bindings, you can type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> to delete the previous word.

Comment: This was what I was looking. But can you tell me where this shortcut comes from? I can't find it in the output of `bind -P`.

Comment: @Siggy it should be named `backward-kill-word`.

Comment: @Siggy `Backspace` appears as `\C-?`, because it's ASCII character number 127, which is a control character (a non-printable character).

Comment: This doesn't work for me.

Comment: `$ bind -P |grep backward-kill-word` says `backward-kill-word can be found on "\M-\C-h", "\M-\C-?".`