# How to remove part of path in terminal?

Tags: bash

Suppose I've typed

```
cd Documents/dir1/
```

I want to remove only `dir1` from that input so that I get

```
cd Documents/
```

This has been asked in in [remove part of path](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28771/how-to-remove-last-part-of-a-path-in-bash), but I couldn't find what I was looking for.

Comment: In what way do you mean without the obvious "use delete/backspace"? And what relevance are "_Ubuntu keyboard shortcuts_"?

Comment: Can you comment on why [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/28773/377345) to the question you mentioned doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to remove `dir1`.