# I read "Advantages of using set -o vi" and have a question about same

Tags: shell, text-processing, command-line, terminal, zsh

Followup-up on [Advantages of using set -o vi](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/30454)

I'm learning vi and know nothing about emacs.  I also type poorly and frequently need to edit my commands in the terminal.  The idea of using vi to edit my poorly typed commands sounds like a good idea.  At present when editing, I use arrow keys to get to the place I want to change.  I'm thinking of using: *set -o vi* .  However, there was an admonishment in the article (somewhat down the page by mattb): *I set up my vim to immediately add a # at the start of the line when I do Esc-v to protect myself from this possibility.*
So, my question?  How do I do as suggested by mattb?

Thank  you for any reply.  larry

If I placed this question in the wrong place, I apologize!!

Comment: What article are you talking about? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: That `v` in command mode to launch `vi` is a ksh/bash thing. In `zsh`, `v` enters visual mode like in `vim`. There is however a `edit-command-line` custom widget that you could bind to some key to get a similar behaviour as in ksh.

Comment: Thank you!  I am new at all of this (terminal usage and programming in general); truthfully, a reentry to this.  I had used bash but Apple decided (a while ago) to switch to zsh.  I keep reading that bash and zsh are very similar.  From your comment, it appears that I can't use `set -o v` .  Is that correct?  That would make my original question mute.  I guess I'll keep using arrow keys to locate and edit my poorly typed commands.

Comment: Apple decided to switch the default shell for new users to be `zsh`.  If you want or need to use `bash`, by all means use `bash`.  The only person to whom the shell you use matters is yourself.

Comment: I have one important server where, over 10 years go, I switched the shell to `set -o vi` mode. Though I'm a Vim user, every time I go into that shell, I don't like it. I don't bother reverting it though.